# Why doesn't pointwise convergence imply uniform convergence? ('proof' inside)

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n, f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ for $n=1,2,3,...$ and suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(t) =f(t) $, ie for all $t \in [a,b], \epsilon>0$ there exists $N(t, \epsilon) \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for $n>N, |f_n(t) - f(t) |<\epsilon. $

Consider the set $A = \lbrace N(t, \epsilon) :t \in [a, b] \rbrace$. Then for all epsilon greater than zero why wouldn't it be true for $ n>\sup A$ (which is an integer), that $|f_n(t) - f(t) |< \epsilon$, for all $t\in[a, b] $? (ie the sequence is uniformly convergent)

Comment: What if $\sup A = \infty$?

Comment: how could that be? By pointwise convergence there is an $N_t$ for each $t$  in the interval so wouldnt the sup (max?) be one of these $N_t's$?

Comment: @Arthur, No. Improving pointwise convergence to uniform convergence occurs only in rare occasions. For instance, Dini's theorem tells that if *increasing* sequence of continuous functions on a compact set converges pointwise to a continuous function, then the convergence is indeed uniform.

Comment: You are taking supremum of $N(t, \epsilon)$ over uncountably many $t$'s. There is no reason to expect that this is finite. For instance, if $f_n, f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ are such that $f_n(t) = t^n$ and $f$ is the pointwise limit, then for $t \in (0, 1)$ and $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ we have the lower bound $$N(t, \epsilon) \geq  \left\lceil \frac{\log\epsilon}{\log t} \right\rceil - 1$$ and hence $\sup A = \infty$.

Comment: ok so the uncountability is the issue. what assumptions would allows the uncountable set of $N(t,\epsilon)$s to have a supremum?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $f_n(t)=t^n$ on $[0,1]$ then $f(t)=0$ for $t\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=1$. Then
$$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f_n(t)-f(t)|=\sup_{t\in[0,1)}t^n=1$$
and the convergence is not uniform in $[0,1]$.

What is $N(t,\epsilon)$ in this case? What is $\sup \{ N(t, \epsilon) :t \in [a, b] \}$?